# title redirecting in htaccess for redirecting url or something like this

Tags: php, codeigniter

## i want to redirect this please guide me

*form*

> http://example.com/babycare/general_help/category.php?id=10

*to*

http://example.com/babycare/article/category/10

*the id should change deynamicly i.e id may b 10,12,or 23 etc*

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

**Try use on .htaccess:**

```
RewriteRule ^babycare/article/category/([0-9]+)$ babycare/general_help/category.php?id=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one, you need to change some part of it accoriding to your category

```
  RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)/(.+)$ category.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
```